# getting uptime in Weeks, Days, Hours, Minutes

Tags: linux, date, uptime

Basically I an using conky to ssh into an android tv box and get the uptime and display it on the conky screen.

I have this so far, found on net and hacked by me but it works, please amend if its crap

```
uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{print int($6/7),"weeks",$8,"hours,",$9,"minutes."}'
```

and it shows

```
4 weeks 1 hour 1 minute
```

How do I get

```
4 weeks **1 day** 1 hour 1 minute
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you tag your question with `Ubuntu`, below is enough.

```
$ uptime -p
up 4 weeks, 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute
```

see [man uptime](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/uptime.1.html) for Ubuntu.

```
-p, --pretty
      show uptime in pretty format
```

Or with your own script:

```
awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{
    printf("%dweeks, %.fdays, %dhours, %dminutes\n", 
           $5/7, ($5/7-int($5/7))/0.143+.05, $7, $8)
}' <(uptime)
```

Each day~=0.143 week, and we divided the result to `0.143` to get days, then added `0.5` and with `printf`' s `.f` control it will round to next integer number (does as Ceil function).

You may need to change `$5`, `$7` and `$8` with `$6`, `$8` and `$9`.

Comment: Also works on RHEL7 and Fedora 24,. so I suspect it will work in any Linux distro.

Comment: Thanks :  ) Yeah, except OSX, but `awk` version should work I think in all distros